# Where to report if a website copies content from Hinduism SE?

Tags: discussion

Recently I came across a site which has nearly 13 questions on Hinduism, all of which are copied from Hinduism SE without proper attribution or credits: `http://helptothis.com/`.

The question list is available at `http://helptothis.com/search.php?cx=partner-pub-5841492570959972%3Aj8iaqq4aljr&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=hinduism`.

Where can I report this?

Comment: Refer [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

Comment: @iammilind Yeah i know, reported many times. You can even use contact  us and leave it on SE team to handle

Comment: Whats the harm in sharing knowledge?.Even the answers that are posted here are copied from scriptural sources.Do this site own copyright of such knowledge?I joined this site to learn more and to share whatever little that i know.So,i don't see a problem if someone shares content from this site on another.Its a punya karma,atleast thts the way i see it.

Comment: @Rickross Breaking copyright laws can't be considered as punya karma.

Comment: @AnkitSharma But where is copyright involved in all this? Hinduism.SE doesn't have any right on scriptural sources. It's the thought that counts and as rickross said, it is definitely a punya karma.

Comment: @chinmay we are talking about Hinduism.SE question and answer not the scripture. SE don't own scripture but using there QA without permission doesn't seems punya karma to me. SE copyright is similar to wikipedia.

Comment: @AnkitSharma BTW Doing *Punya Karma* leads to Heaven and not doing it **may** lead to Liberation. ;-)

Comment: @iammilind Not doing Punya may lead to liberation ! how come?Opposite of Punya is Papa ,so one is doing papa if he is not doing punya.Doing punya karmas without the desire of obtaining the fruits of them leads to liberation.

Comment: To quote/acknowledge the source is sathvik behaviour

Answer (score 6):

You can report through [contact](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/contact) form:

> [image: screenshot]

You (as a author of post) can also report to the author/company/foundation/owner of respected license e.g Creative Commons, Free Software Foundation etc. if it is a case of license violation and/or attribution.

Yes, <sup>As [commented](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/498/where-to-report-if-a-website-copies-content-from-hinduism-se#comment1571_498) by Ankit Sharma,</sup> Visit [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/260388) for complete guideline which guides on following topics:

- When should I report these sites?
- When should I not report these sites?
- How do I go about reporting these sites?

  > Please contact us directly using the on-site form. Select the **"Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution"** option from the drop-down, and provide as much information as possible. Even if you are reporting an entire site that is scraping many questions, please provide an example of a question on their site and the corresponding question on our site, as well as any Google search terms you used that led you to finding this site. Any other information you might have can be included in the free-form text box.
- I am the author of a scraped post